# Unexpected behavior using the run method for win32ole excel object

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole, vba

I have the following bit of ruby code which works fine

```
require 'WIN32OLE'
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = true
path =  Dir.pwd + '\Testargs.xlsm'
excel.workbooks.open(path)
excel.run('IdontTakeargs')
```

Where IdontTakeargs is a macro in the Testargs.xlsm workbook.

If I attempt to call a macro which takes arguments ie:

```
excel.run('Itakeargs(1)')
```

This code also runs, but for some reason it runs the macro twice. The above snytax is somewhat of a guess as I can't locate an example of calling a macro with arguments.

Any help with what the correct syntax might be or even if what I am attempting to accomplish is even possible (call a macro that accepts arguments from ruby.)

Comment: Could you create a new macro (as simple as possible) with one argument and do excel.run('Mynewmacro(1)')? Does it run twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to pass an argument to a VBA macro seems to be

```
excel.run('Itakeargs', '1')
```

Still, the observed (and reproducable) behaviour is somewhat strange.

Comment: Thanks! did you figure that out through experimentation, or documentation? Also as a side note to future vistors multiple arguments take the form (macroname, arg1, arg2, ...)

Comment: I googled a bit and found some examples in Python using that syntax. Then, I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

To rule out a silly possibility, you didn't have your new code as

```
require 'WIN32OLE'
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = true
path =  Dir.pwd + '\Testargs.xlsm'
excel.workbooks.open(path)
excel.run('IdontTakeargs')
excel.run('Itakeargs(1)')
```

did you? If you did, that'd explain why two macros were run!

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I run the code as you have listed IdontTakeargs will run once, and Itakeargs(1) will run twice